# Запуск функции только при изменении ширины окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, которая должна срабатывать, только если изменяется ширина окна, при этом она не должна реагировать на изменение высоты, как это сделать?

```js
$(window).resize(function () {
  console.log("Размеры окна изменились");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сохранять текущее значение ширины в глобальной переменной и проверять её изменение.

```js
var a = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(window).resize(function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth != a) {
    console.log("Размеры окна изменились");
    a = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```